# WebView and localhost

Tags: android, webview

I am getting google.com inside my WebView, but am not getting my localhost in that.
Can anybody help me?

Comment: Do you mean "loopback interface" by localhost? there is no web server running on your android.

Comment: Are you using emulator or the actual device, please mention

Answer (score 40):

Use 10.0.2.2 instead. This is a special ip address that the emulator routs to local host on your dev machine. assuming that emulator and the webserver are running on the same machine.

Answer (score 10):

Make sure you are loading WebView with full Urls.

```
http://www.google.com
http://10.0.2.2/
```

and not:

```
www.google.com
google.com
```

All of these will work while using Browser, but you must supply a full valid url for WebView. Banged my head against the keyboard for an hour figuring that out.

If you're having connectivity issues in the emulator, try overriding the dns in the build path.

```
Window > Preferences > Android > Launch
Default emulator options: -dns-server 8.8.8.8
```

Answer (score 8):

I have created a website and published it in my local computer using IIS, I tried to access this site in the android emulator using WebView:

> http://localhost:83

with the same results as the OP.

I changed to:

> http://10.0.2.2:83

and worked.

Answer (score 1):

Try your actual ip [with the port number if required] instead of localhost.

Comment: I found that if use 127.0.0.1 emulator will use its loopback interface

Answer (score 1):

Just type localhost name and port like this: `http://127.0.0.1:80`

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a physical device to run, then,

1. make sure your website is running at 192.168.x.xxx:port
2. set the full url in your activity, such as,

   mwebView.loadUrl("http://192.168.1.107:8000/");
3. add

   android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"

   in AndroidManifest.xml to fix 'cleartext not permitted' error caused for not using https

If in emulator, then,

1. host website in localhost (127.0.0.1:port)
2. for url

   mwebView.loadUrl("http://127.0.0.1:3000");
3. previous 3rd step

(Make sure to remove the manifest permission before release. Or it would be a security concern for your app.)

Answer (score 0):

I added the IP Address of the local server and it is working fine.
You can find you ip address by going to

### COMMAND PROMPT

```
type> ipconfig
```

Now, add the ipv4 IP Address shown in your Webview URL. It will work fine.

Comment: You can add port as well e.g. 192.168.x.1:80/index_file.extension