# Kotlin: LoadURL onReceivedError() not firing

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

Simple kotlin app under android studio that makes a loadURL to a local address:-

The function often fails, probably due to local net latency with:

Web Page not available
The web page at http://192.168.1.144/apikey/webcam could not be loaded because:
net: ERR_ADDRESS_UNREACHABLE

I have

```
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

in the manifest, and the loadurl often is fine

In order to capture the error and provide a message an
`onReceivedError()`
action is used.

It never fires

Is the syntax of the onReceivedError correct? It refers to WebView rather than my instance myWebview (which causes a reference error), and I've moved the scope around to no effect.

The Android Studio comment says that the function is never used. A big hint, but I can't see which scope to place it in.

Or is this type of error one of those not caught by OnReceivedError. If so, how which function would?
Ideally I'd like to increase the 'wait' time of the LoadUrl function so that the lazy local IP can respond.

I've copied this from other examples.

I'd really welcome some help please

Here is my class code:

```
    class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    
        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                // Create the NotificationChannel
                val name = getString(R.string.channel_name)
                val descriptionText = getString(R.string.channel_description)
                val importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT
                val CHANNEL_ID = "only_channel"
                val mChannel = NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, name, importance)
                mChannel.description = descriptionText
                // Register the channel with the system; you can't change the importance
                // or other notification behaviors after this
                val notificationManager = getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
                notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel)
            }
    
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                // Create channel to show notifications.
                val channelId = getString(R.string.default_notification_channel_id)
                val channelName = getString(R.string.default_notification_channel_name)
                val notificationManager = getSystemService(NotificationManager::class.java)
                notificationManager?.createNotificationChannel(NotificationChannel(channelId,
                        channelName, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH))
            }
    
            val myWebView: WebView = findViewById(R.id.webview)
    
            /*myWebView.loadUrl("https://amazon.co.uk")*/
            myWebView.webViewClient = WebViewClient()
            myWebView.setWebViewClient(object : WebViewClient() {
                fun onReceivedError(view: WebView  , errorCode: Int, description: String, failingUrl: String, getContext: Context) {
                    Log.i("WEB_VIEW_TEST", "error code:$errorCode")
                    Toast.makeText(getContext, "Webcam not reachable",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show()
    
                }
            })
            WebView.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(true)
            /*5 March 2021*/
            myWebView.clearCache(true)
    
            myWebView.loadUrl("http://192.168.1.144/apikey/webcam")
    
            val disable_button: Button = findViewById(R.id.disable)
            disable_button.setOnClickListener {
                myWebView.loadUrl("http://192.168.1.144/apikey/disable")
            }
    
            fun onReceivedError(
                    view: WebView,
                    request: WebResourceRequest,
                    error: WebResourceError
            ) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Webcam not reachable", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15103463/how-to-access-the-local-host-server-with-web-view-in-android

Comment: Exactly the same response