# can not load http url in webview - xamarin android

Tags: xamarin.android

we are unable to load http url in webview- xmarin andriod. In the  mainactiviy.cs , we have written below code.

```
using Android.App;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using AndroidX.AppCmpat.App;
using Android.Webkit;

namespace Tele_Medicine
{
    [Activity(Label = "@string/app_name", Theme = "@style/AppTheme", MainLauncher = true)]
    public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity
    {
        WebView web_view;
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);

            web_view = FindViewById<WebView>(Resource.Id.webview);
            web_view.Settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
            web_view.Settings.DomStorageEnabled = true;
            web_view.Settings.SetSupportMultipleWindows(true);
            web_view.Settings.JavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically = true;
            web_view.Settings.AllowContentAccess = true;
            web_view.Settings.AllowFileAccess = true;
            web_view.Settings.AllowFileAccessFromFileURLs = true;
            web_view.Settings.AllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs=true;
            web_view.SetWebViewClient(new TeleWebViewClient());
          
            web_view.LoadUrl("http://ay.vkrto4dtemp.org:8080/tmui-v1.0/#/login");
            
        }
        public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, [GeneratedEnum] Android.Content.PM.Permission[] grantResults)
        {
            Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

            base.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        }
    }
}
```

In the android manifiest.xml , we have written below code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" package="com.companyname.tele_medicine" android:installLocation="auto">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="28" android:targetSdkVersion="30" android:usesCleartextTraffic="false" />
    <application android:allowBackup="true" android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" android:label="@string/app_name" android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" android:supportsRtl="true" android:theme="@style/AppTheme"></application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
</manifest>
```

Please help me to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare the `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` not false in the android manifiest.xml.

The [official document](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element#usesCleartextTraffic) said:

> Indicates whether the app intends to use cleartext network traffic, such as cleartext HTTP. The default value for apps that target API level 27 or lower is "true". Apps that target API level 28 or higher default to "false".
>
> When the attribute is set to "false", platform components, for
> example, HTTP and FTP stacks, DownloadManager, and MediaPlayer, refuse
> the app's requests to use cleartext traffic.

Comment: Hi Liyun Zhang, I have tried with both ways android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" or "false" but still getting same problem.

Comment: Can you load this url in the Browser? Or can you load this url if you change http to https? @RajuGaddam

Comment: In the browser, url is loading but still facing same issue with http. we have only http url only...

Comment: Did you use a localhost? Please check this link about [accessing local host in the android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15103463/how-to-access-the-local-host-server-with-web-view-in-android). @RajuGaddam

Comment: We are not using local host. we have http  url

Comment: But why there is 8080 in the url? I even can't load the url you provided in my phone and my computer. @RajuGaddam

Comment: i have given dummy uri mentioned in the  question.  main url is different. you can try this one http://assamtmc.piramalswasthya.org:8080/tmui-v1.0/#/login

Comment: I still can't load it in my device. Where did you load it successfully? @RajuGaddam

Comment: I ma able to load url  in my device

Comment: The same result. The browser can't access it means the problem is the website not the webview. @RajuGaddam

Comment: I am able to access from the browser of mobile also. please check once again

Comment: I still can't load it in my device. Did you use wifi when you try to load it? Did you try to use 4g to load this url? @RajuGaddam

Comment: it is loading in my mobile browser with wifi and 4g